# how to use LookUpRecord processor?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I tried to join two csv file based on id with respect to the below reference.

[How to join two CSVs with Apache Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908838/how-to-join-two-csvs-with-apache-nifi)

i'm using NiFi-1.3.0

Now i have two csv files.

1.**custom.csv**

```
No,Name,ID,Age
1,Hik,2201,33
2,Kio,3300,22
```

**2.gender.csv**

```
ID,Name,Sex
2201,Hik,Male
3300,Kio,Female
```

I try to combine those tables with **"ID"** like following endresult.

```
No,Name,Sex,ID,Age
1,Hik,Male,2201,33
2,Kio,Female,3300,22
```

I have using following processor structure.

```
GetFile-SplitText-ExtractText-LookUpRecord-PutFile
```

In that lookup record i have configured

```
RecordReader = "CSVReader"
RecordWriter="FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter"
LookUpService="SimpleCSVFileLookUpService"

ResultRecordPath-->/Key
key-->/ID
```

In that LookUpService i have given **path of the "gender.csv" and setted LookUpKeyColumn and LookUpValueColumn to be "ID".**

In that FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter i have given text value`"${No},${Name},${ID},${Age},${Sex}"`

It yields below result only.

```
No,Name,ID,Age,
1,Hik,2201,33,
2,Kio,3300,22,
```

It doesn't have "sex" column.

I think i haven't configured correctly.

i don't know how to use ResultRecordPath & one dynamic attribute(Key)  specification in LookUpRecord?

**Can anyone guide me to solve my issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was asked and responded to on the apache nifi mailing list.

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/5041018de5a5be773055bb2709427eed4131c3923262b55051fb1324@%3Cusers.nifi.apache.org%3E

Comment: Please no links - they might break in the future.