# is it possible to merge 2 json flowFile and create result json flowFile in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 2 json Flowfile generated from different source(DB/file system).

First process generates json multiple FlowFiles in below format:

```
{
"sku_id": 1,
"desc": "desc1"
}
```

Second flowFile has multiple json array of sku's in file:

```
    {
        "sku_id": 1,
        "name": "nam1"
    },
    {
        "sku_id": 2,
        "name": "nam2"
    }
```

I want to merge above 2 json and create a result json as below:

```
    {
        "sku_id": 1,
        "name": "nam1",
        "desc": "desc1"
    }
```

Is this kind of merge process possible in nifi, closest that I could search for is QueryRecord processor, but did not find any example around json.

Any idea how do I merge the 2 flowfiles?

Comment: A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908838/how-to-join-two-csvs-with-apache-nifi

Comment: i think it's possible to use MergeContent to merge both files into one json file, then use ExecuteScript to parse and merge data logically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two CSVs with Apache Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908838/how-to-join-two-csvs-with-apache-nifi)