# Merge two JSON flowfile together in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

i want to merge two flowfile that contain JSON object by same specified attribute...

**flow1:**

```
attribute:    
xuuid = 123456

content:
{
"sname":"jack",
"id":"00001",
"state":"NY"
}
```

**flow2:**

```
attribute:    
xuuid = 123456

content:
{
"country":"US",
"date":"1983"
}
```

and i expect this form of data in single output flow:

**desired_flow:**

```
attribute:    
xuuid = 123456

content:
{
"sname":"jack",
"id":"00001",
"state":"NY",
"country":"US",
"date":"1983"
}
```

how do i play with this? MergeContent processor or MergeRecord?
i think mergerecord can handle it but i confusing on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is a streaming join and it is not something that NiFi really does, similar question and answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42909221/5650316

The merge processors are made to merge pieces of data one after another, not to perform a streaming join. For example, if you have many small json messages you would want to use MergeContent or MergeRecord to merge together thousands of them into a single flow file before writing to HDFS.

Answer (score 5):

Yes MergeContent can do this for you.

I use **EvalJson** --> **MergeContent** --> **AttributesToJson**

I have posted a template here you can use to play around.
**[Apache NiFi Merge Json Template](http://www.aodba.com/how-to-merge-two-json-flowfiles-in-apache-nifi/)**

The **MergeContent** must have this settings : "Keep all attributes","2 a num of entires" ,"Delimiters strategy is Text"

Comment: how about the attribute(xuuid)? this merge must be done with correlation of this attribute...

Comment: using EvalJson is more consume system RAM (because of storing attributes in RAM) than other methods and i not prefer this solution. two json i presented above is sample and in real work every flow size of my work(multi field of text) is near 10MB, then it's not probable for using that processor.

Comment: i use merge record in other project and that is so useful and powerful processor... i think JSON tree reader and JSON writer can handle this but because of it's complexity  i confused in and i need to who has expert on it.

Comment: i am using EvalJson with 1 Gb payloads and have no issue, the json reader + writer will use same lib to brake down the json flowfile anyway.

Comment: in just two flow file it's work, but in my case flows not ordinal and one flow must merge with other flow from other stream that attribute is same as it.... i test your stream and change time of record generator and then result came wrong!

Comment: well that was not in the scope of you initial question

Answer (score 1):

[An answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124212/897137) shows how this can be done with `MergeContent` followed by a `JoltTransformJSON`.

Like the OP here, I wanted to merge on a particular attribute (`filename`, in my case) so my `MergeContent` config was *slightly* different:

```
Merge Strategy: Bin-Packing Algorithm
Merge Format: Binary Concatenation
Correlation Attribute Name: filename  # or xuuid, or whatever you want
Minimum Number of Entries: 2
Delimiter Strategy: Text
Header: [
Footer: ]
Demarcator: ,
```

After that, the second part of the solution is the same:

> Then transfer to JoltTrasnformJSON and set Jolt Transformation DSL to Shift and Jolt Specification to:
>
> ```
> {
>   "*": {
>     "*": "&"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This should do the job :)

Smashing solution, all kudos to @[Ben Yaakobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10701396/ben-yaakobi).

The only thing I can add, by way of explanation, is that @[Bryan Bende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5650316/bryan-bende)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167182/897137) is technically true, i.e. NiFi isn't designed for this kind of thing. Accordingly, the answer above is a bit of a hack:

- In the first part, `MergeContent` actually ignores the fact we're working with JSON altogether (its `Binary Concatenation` means it's just dealing with the content as raw bytes). It just "fakes" merging the two records into a JSON array by using Header, Footer and Decmarcator settings as shown, which *happen* to be JSON syntax.
- Then in the second part, Jolt is able to parse that munged text as valid JSON, and apply its transformational magic.

For a better understanding of the Jolt syntax used, here are some helpful resources on the topic:

- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350
- https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java
- https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

See also [some alternative approaches mentioned here](http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/join-two-datasets-td7039.html). In particular, I think the approach of using Use `MergeRecord` / `MergeContent` with a correlation attribute or Defragment mode, followed by `QueryRecord` with `COALESCE` and `GROUP BY` in order to join together the columns from both datasets, would be most relevant to this question (although I haven't tried this myself).