# merge json with JoinEnrichment

Tags: apache-nifi

I have two payloads and want to merge them into single JSON object (streaming join). the link describes a task like mine [I have two Json payload. I want to merge them in a single Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118389/i-have-two-json-payload-i-want-to-merge-them-in-a-single-json-object/55124212?newreg=94f6e01cce044803a679a6a6a5e58205). How to realize the action using the JoinEnrichment processor?

Sequentially merged file original + Enrichment

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with information to make it answerable. E.g. which programming language are you considering? The tag [tag:apache] (see its usage information) doesn't give it away and is likely wrong. Also, what have you tried so far? Consider to provide a [mcve]. (Note: Based on the linked question, I'm changing [tag:apache] to [tag:apache-nifi])

Comment: 1) Original: 
```SELECT [DateTime], h.TagName, Value, Quality
FROM historian.Runtime.dbo.[History] h
  inner join (select '2024/02/14 04:59:00' as dt, 'SMT_000000000001.Accel' as tagname union
select '2024/02/14 04:59:00' as dt, 'SMT_000000000002.Accel' as tagname union
select '2024/02/14 04:59:00' as dt, 'SMT_000000000003.Accel' as tagname```
2)enrichment:
  ```) t on t.tagname = h.[TagName] and h.[DateTime] >t.dt where wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' and h.[TagName] in ('SMT_000000000001.Accel',
'SMT_000000000002.Accel',
'SMT_000000000003.Accel')
  order by h.[DateTime]```