Merge two JSONs in Apache NIFI
Input JSON 1
{
  "property_name" : "TEST REAL ",
  "x_read" : "f6d139",
  "y_read" : "348be3"
}

Input JSON 2
{
  "property_name": "TEST REAL",
  "property_link": "https://sffff/sadsadd/",
  "location": [
    {
      "location_name": "01 green",
      "location_type_name": "Green",
      "location_conditions": {
        "timestamp": "2024-04-24 07:32:07",
        "num_samples": 10,
        "img_extent": {
          "lng": -5.32,
          "lnd": -15.5
        },
        "avg": 31.76,
        "avg_color": "#4EC0003DA",
        "rating": "High"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Expected Output JSON
{
  "property_name": "TEST REAL",
  "property_link": "https://sffff/sadsadd/",
  "x_read": "f6d139",
  "y_read": "348be3",
  "location": [
    {
      "location_name": "01 green",
      "location_type_name": "Green",
      "location_conditions": {
        "timestamp": "2024-04-24 07:32:07",
        "num_samples": 10,
        "img_extent": {
          "lng": -5.32,
          "lnd": -15.5
        },
        "avg": 31.76,
        "avg_color": "#4EC0003DA",
        "rating": "High"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I need to merge both JSONs into JSON using property_name JSON key and need to get the expected output JSON as shown above.

Hi, How are you getting the two json input? are you getting them for completely independent from each other or are you getting one first, then based on the first you are getting a second input through some downstream processor.

I'm getting them from two independent paths

Hi Bhadraka, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52141740/5841306 might give you the idea

Hi, can you please answer this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78607774/convert-a-json-using-jolt-format?noredirect=1#comment138587472_78607774
