Convert a JSON using JOLT Format
Input JSON
[
  {
    "collectionname": "Property name",
    "idgroup_uuid": "7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f",
    "iduser_uuid": "5f9c09ea-6332-7541-9632-4a9a0ee768f1"
  },
  [
    {
      "zone_name": "01 green",
      "zone_type_name": "Green",
      "conditions": {
        "timestamp": "2024-06-11 06:35:41",
        "num_samples": 12,
        "img_extent": {
          "min_lng": -5.877219,
          "max_lng": -5.876672,
          "min_lat": 54.220024,
          "max_lat": 54.220338
        },
        "moisture_avg": 29.01,
        "moisture_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387721?attribute=M&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "moisture_avg_color": "#4EC3DA",
        "moisture_avg_rating": "High",
        "ec_avg": 0.21,
        "ec_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387721?attribute=E&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "ec_avg_color": "#2D882D",
        "ec_avg_rating": "Optimal",
        "salinity_index_avg": 0.73,
        "salinity_index_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387721?attribute=S&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "salinity_index_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "salinity_index_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "surface_heat_f_avg": 49.21,
        "surface_heat_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387721?attribute=T&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "surface_heat_f_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "surface_heat_f_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "soil_temp_f_avg": 48.98,
        "soil_temp_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387721?attribute=ST&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "soil_temp_f_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "soil_temp_f_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "notes": []
      },
      "pins": []
    },
    {
      "zone_name": "02 Green",
      "zone_type_name": "Green",
      "conditions": {
        "timestamp": "2024-06-11 06:58:30",
        "num_samples": 12,
        "img_extent": {
          "min_lng": -5.87333,
          "max_lng": -5.872946,
          "min_lat": 54.222294,
          "max_lat": 54.222509
        },
        "moisture_avg": 29.3,
        "moisture_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387712?attribute=M&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "moisture_avg_color": "#4EC3DA",
        "moisture_avg_rating": "High",
        "ec_avg": 0.21,
        "ec_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387712?attribute=E&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "ec_avg_color": "#2D882D",
        "ec_avg_rating": "Optimal",
        "salinity_index_avg": 0.73,
        "salinity_index_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387712?attribute=S&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "salinity_index_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "salinity_index_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "surface_heat_f_avg": 49.63,
        "surface_heat_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387712?attribute=T&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "surface_heat_f_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "surface_heat_f_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "soil_temp_f_avg": 49.55,
        "soil_temp_f_img": "https://api.pogoturfpro.com/api/partner/maya/insight/5387712?attribute=ST&key=05127be738e28884c2eba2585968eb687aa0cd20dadc299f5282ff6bf82f5e5b",
        "soil_temp_f_avg_color": "#AF4440",
        "soil_temp_f_avg_rating": "Critically Low",
        "notes": []
      },
      "pins": []
    }
  ]
]

Expected Output JSON
[
  {
    "Time": "2024-06-11 06:35:41",
    "VMC": 29.01,
    "EC": 0.21,
    "Temp_Soil_F": 48.98,
    "Temp_Soil": 9.433,
    "Latitude": 54.220181,
    "Longitude": -5.876945,
    "idgroup": "group(7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f)",
    "iduser": "user(5f9c09ea-6332-7541-9632-4a9a0ee768f1)",
    "Rod_Length": "S",
    "Soil_type": "D",
    "VWC_Mode": "V"
  },
  {
    "Time": "2024-06-11 06:58:30",
    "VMC": 29.3,
    "EC": 0.21,
    "Temp_Soil_F": 49.55,
    "Temp_Soil": 9.75,
    "Latitude": 54.222401,
    "Longitude": -5.873138,
    "idgroup": "group(7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f)",
    "iduser": "user(5f9c09ea-6332-7541-9632-4a9a0ee768f1)",
    "Rod_Length": "S",
    "Soil_type": "D",
    "VWC_Mode": "V"
  }
]

Specifications:
Rod_Length, Soil_type & VWC_Mode are hardcoded values
idgroup is idgroup_uuid
iduser is iduser_uuid
Time is timestamp
VWC is moisture_avg
EC is ec_avg
Temp_Soil_F is soil_temp_f_avg
Temp_Soil is celcius(soil_temp_f_avg) - convert soil_temp_f_avg to celsius
Latitude is (min_lat+ max_lat) / 2
Longitude is (min_lng + max_lng)/2

Does this answer your question? Modify JOLT Expression to get Output JSON

and already this one

no this Input JSON is different a bit from the you mentioned

Hi this spec will help you resolve your query.
Updated the spec :
Also added logic to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@(1,idgroup_uuid)": "[#2].idgroup",
          "@(1,iduser_uuid)": "[#2].iduser",
          "conditions": {
            "#S": "[#3].Rod_Length",
            "#D": "[#3].Soil_type",
            "#V": "[#3].VWC_Mode",
            "timestamp": "[#3].Time",
            "moisture_avg": "[#3].VMC",
            "ec_avg": "[#3].EC",
            "soil_temp_f_avg": "[#3].Temp_Soil_F",
            "img_extent": {
              "min_lng": "[#4].min_lng",
              "max_lng": "[#4].max_lng",
              "max_lat": "[#4].max_lat",
              "min_lat": "[#4].min_lat"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Latitude": "=avg(@(1,min_lat),@(1,max_lat))",
        "Longitude": "=avg(@(1,min_lng),@(1,max_lng))",
        "Temp_Soil": "=doubleSum(@(1,Temp_Soil_F),-32)",
        "idgroup": "=concat(group,'(',@(1,idgroup),))",
        "iduser": "=concat(user,'(',@(1,iduser),))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Temp_Soil_F": "=divide(@(1,Temp_Soil_F),1.8)"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "min_lng": "",
        "max_lng": "",
        "max_lat": "",
        "min_lat": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Rod_Length": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,Time)": "[#4].Time",
            "@(2,VMC)": "[#4].VMC",
            "@(2,Temp_Soil_F)": "[#4].Temp_Soil_F",
            "@(2,Temp_Soil)": "[#4].Temp_Soil",
            "@(2,Latitude)": "[#4].Latitude",
            "@(2,Longitude)": "[#4].Longitude",
            "@(2,idgroup)": "[#4].idgroup",
            "@(2,iduser)": "[#4].iduser",
            "@(2,Rod_Length)": "[#4].Rod_Length",
            "@(2,Soil_type)": "[#4].Soil_type",
            "@(2,VWC_Mode)": "[#4].VWC_Mode",
            "@(2,EC)": "[#4].EC"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Explanation:
First shift spec will do the transformation to the array required format.
"@(1,idgroup_uuid)": "[#2].idgroup" // @--> will pick value from 1 level up and place it among the array.
Everything inside "conditions" --> will be placed in an array object.
"#S": "[#3].Rod_Length" --> # in shift operation on LHS means adding default value.
Second "modify-overwrite-beta" --> will do average for longitude and latitude.
Third Spec "remove" will remove nonrequired fields.
Note : Temp_Soil_F convertion to celcius wont work with Jolt we need to add a logic for it in Java.
I hope this helps you in getting the required output.

I need the idgroup and user to be inside brackets as in the expected output json
"group(7750ceae-0528-44cb-9aeb-8865602d7f6f)"

Hi I have updated the spec that will generate the required output.
Also added a logic to convert  Fahrenheit to Celsius.

I need the id user and id_group within brackets like in expected output json
"user(user_id)"
"group(group_id)"

Hey I updated the spec with concatenation logic on the 2 fields. I think that will help you.
Please accept the logic if it helps.
